# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{2k+1}{k^2(k+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital, partial-fractions

I have to find the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k+1}{k^2(k+1)^2}.$$ I tried to make it into a telescopic series but it doesn't really work out...

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k+1}{k^2(k+1)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1-k}{k^2}+\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{(k+1)^2} \right)$$ so that is what I did using telescopic...

I said that:

$$\frac{2k+1}{k^2(k+1)^2}=\frac{Ak+B}{k^2}+\frac C{k+1}+\frac D{(k+1)^2}$$ but now as I look at it.. I guess I should "build up the power" with the ${k^2}$ too, right?

Comment: Show us what you did with the telescoping series.

Comment: @heropup in a sec

Comment: Hint: $\;\; \dfrac{\color{red}{k^2}+2k+1 \color{red}{-k^2}}{k^2(k+1)^2}$

Comment: @dxiv Thank you. I was too blind to see... Sorry for asking this trivial question.... I shouldn't, it's not my best day. My apologies.

Comment: @C.Cristi Next time you'll see it. That's what practice is for.

Comment: @heropup I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\bigg[\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\bigg]$$